# How long takes store-bought fried tofu to go bad?

Tags: storage-lifetime, refrigerator, deep-frying, tofu

According to expiration date in the package it only takes a week. Maybe it can keep for longer?

Answer (score 0):

Expiration dates can be quite arbitrary. When tofu goes off, you should be able to smell it and it would also begin to taste sour. You also want to watch out for molds. Other than that, depending on the type of tofu and how they are packed/pasteurized, they can last longer than a week or two.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a source for this, but I keep mine for over a week, usually using it within two. The most important part is to replace the water every day that it soaks in.

Comment: Does fried tofu soak in water?